# Replace identical elements in XML separately using ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am currently working on a script that reads a XML file, parses through the sub nodes and changes some of them.

Assuming this is an example XML:

```
<graph id="Graph">
  <node id="Read">
    <parameters class="com.bc.ceres.binding.dom.XppDomElement">
      <file>somepath</file>
    </parameters>
  </node>
  <node id="Write">
    <parameters class="com.bc.ceres.binding.dom.XppDomElement">
      <file>somedifferentpath</file>
    </parameters>
  </node>
</graph>
```

The goal is find the "file" nodes and replace both entries. However, these are different.

This is the code I have, replace all "file" entries:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('my.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for file in root.iter('file'):
  file.text = str("new_file")
```

Your help is highly appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: describe the rules of replacement. Are there only 2 `file` nodes?

Comment: yes, there are only 2 "file" nodes

Comment: again, *describe the rules of replacement*, post the replacement values

Comment: It is not clear what you are having problems with. Do you get errors?